# How to combine Datatables but add columns together if they have the same header? (need guidance or resources)

Tags: c#, linq, datatable

I am brand new at using Datatables.
I am trying to take two data tables and combine them and if the two tables have columns with matching headers then add the data in those columns together into a new column.

Another issue is that the headers are being created dynamically so I never know what the name of the header will be.

**DataTable 1:**

| TeamName | Date1 | Date2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| First | int value | int value |
| Second | int value | int value |

**DataTable 2:**

| TeamName | Date2 | Date3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| First | int value | int value |
| Second | int value | int value |

**New Table:**

| TeamName | Date1 | Date2 | Date3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| First | int value | int value1 + int value2 | int value |
| Second | int value | int value1 + int value2 | int value |

If anyone has any insight on how to even get start with doing this with C# and/or LINQ I would really appreciate it.

I have some code but it just combines the tables by including everything, it basically looks like the two tables just side by side, nothing is mixed together.

```
 DataTable targetTable = dt1.Clone();
 var dt2Columns = dt2.Columns.OfType<DataColumn>().Select(dc =>
            new DataColumn(dc.ColumnName, dc.DataType, dc.Expression, dc.ColumnMapping));
var dt2FinalColumns = from dc in dt2Columns.AsEnumerable()
                 where targetTable.Columns.Contains(dc.ColumnName) == false
                                  select dc;
 targetTable.Columns.AddRange(dt2FinalColumns.ToArray());
 var rowData = from row1 in dt1.AsEnumerable()
              join row2 in dt2.AsEnumerable()
             on row1.Field<string>("ScrumTeam") equals row2.Field<string>("ScrumTeam")
                          select row1.ItemArray.Concat(row2.ItemArray.Where(r2 => row1.ItemArray.Contains(r2) == false)).ToArray();
foreach (object[] values in rowData)
      targetTable.Rows.Add(values);
```

Comment: Can you get to the source data of the DataTables? May be much easier.

Comment: @GertArnold unfortunately I cannot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure LINQ is making your life any easier here

```
//ensure the dt2 column exists in dt1
foreach(DataColumn dc2 in dt2.Columns)
  if(!dt1.Columns.Contains(dc2.ColumnName))
    dt1.Columns.Add(dc2.Name, dc2.DataType);

//index the rows
var d = dt1.Rows.Cast<DataRow>().ToDictionary(r => r["TeamName"]);

//merge the tables, dt2 into dt1
foreach(DataRow r2 in dt2){
  DataRow r1;

  //handle dt2 team name absence from dt1
  if(!d.ContainsKey(r2["TeamName"])){
    d[r2["TeamName"]] = r1 = dt.NewRow();
    dt1.AddRow(r1);
  }

  //index now surely contains r1; get it
  r1 = d[r2["TeamName"]];

  //merge data from 2 into 1
  foreach(DataColumn dc2 in dt2.Columns){

    //skip the PK
    if(dc2.ColumnName == "TeamName")
      continue;

    //all the values seem to be int. if not true add some "if type is..." handling here
    r1[dc2.ColumnName] = (int)r1[dc2.ColumnName] + (int)r2[dc2.ColumnName];
  }
}
```

Your code says "ScrumTeam" but question tables says "TeamName" - you may have to adjust the code above to cater for your scenario(treat as pseudocode)

Comment: I think this line, `d[r2["TeamName"]] = r1 = dt.NewRow();` should use `dt2` instead of `dt` like this, `d[r2["TeamName"]] = r1 = dt2.NewRow();`  Is that what you intended?